# Android ScrollView disable Inertial scrolling

Tags: android, scrollview

In my activity I reference ScrollView. According to the requirements, I should disable the inertial scrolling of ScrollView. How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

These worked form me, but I'm not sure if it is good for performance.

What I did was create a new View extending the ScrollView and override the onTouchEvent method:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {


    switch (ev.getAction()){
        case ACTION_UP:

            return false;
        default:
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

perhaps, you should also check the source code of the ScrollView to check if there is anything important else to do.

Here you have the source code at dispose:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ScrollView.java

Answer (score -5):

Try this,

```
Scroll.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Comment: What I want to disable is inertial scrolling not the vertical scroll bar. Scroll.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false) will cause the vertical scroll bar can't be seen.

Comment: you cannot do that, see ScrollView sources and find a field called mScroller

Comment: Thank pskink very much.Then do you know the timing of inertial scrolling ? In my project,I will transform long-press key event to key down event.Then I handle the key down event(call the method scrollTo of ScrollView).Then I have noticed that after about 2-4 seconds of long-press,the inertial scrolling may appear.The precent is very low(about 5 percent).So I want to know the accurate timing.